# Ruby assigning a variable to one of two defined alternatives

Tags: ruby

I was wandering about the correct way to do the following.

```
 a = b or c
```

where only one of b or c will be defined.

EDIT: 
Thanks for the answers, just to clarify by not defined they are not defined at all (i.e not nil)

Comment: as you know working with undefined variables is poor practice, but I am sure you have a reason, what's the context?

Comment: @tokland it could be a symptom of bad design. It's inversion of control where i'm reusing the same function to do almost the same thing but in one context one variable will be there in the second the other.

Comment: well, we'd need to see that code, but probably it could be refactored, try to send the non-set variables with a nil.

Comment: thanks for the tip and I'll look at refactoring so they're sent as nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only one or the other actually exists, you'll need to use `defined?` for local variables.

```
a = defined? b ? b : c
```

With instance variables it is a little easier, assuming neither value should be falsy, since they are implicitly `nil` before they are defined:

```
a = @b || @c
```